# How to change default error page for tomcat on server level and not on the application level?

Tags: java, tomcat, server, configuration, tomcat7

I have an application on Tomcat as `https:abc:8443/appname/login` which I use. I have configured the application such that if I search `https://abc:8443/appname/prasfag.txt`, my custom error page gets displayed.

However if I search `https://abc:8443/prags.txt`, the tomcat shows the default Error 404 page. I want the tomcat to show a custom page when I access `https://abc:8443/prags.txt`.

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

In your tomcat web.xml you can configure HTTP redirect pages. Just insert

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>-xxx-</error-code>
 <location>/your/custom/html/path.html</location>
</error-page>
```

in your web.xml